# How to run a function after the end of the loop in which ajax function is executed?

Tags: javascript, ajax, for-loop, async-await

I have a function in which a loop and another ajax function is executed in it. I need that after all ajax functions have been executed, a function that reports completion is launched.

```
function AddAllproducts() {

    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('product_id');
    
    for (var index = 0; index < checkboxes.length; index++) {
      if (checkboxes[index].checked) {
        addProduct(checkboxes[index].value);   // ajax
      }
    }

    done();
  }
}

function done(){
  alert('Done!');
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem, are you getting an error when you run your code?

Comment: I think you're looking for Promise.all(arrayOfPromises), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: No, i'm not getting error.

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it